# How do i design scrollable text view in layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I'm not getting this "Scrollable Text View" part.. It messes up..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use a ScrollView actually.

Just set the

```
android:maxLines = "a number"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your TextView in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

in your code.

it will scrolls automatically.